# Removing Item From Basket Opencart Custom button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, e-commerce, opencart

Basically When a customer 'Likes' our Facebook page i add an item to the cart, but to ensure they don't take huge advantage of this offer i would like to remove the item from the cart should they unlike the page.

So using an Ajax call i would like to remove an item from the basket. Now i have noticed that removing an item from the basket you need a product key.

It makes a get request as such:

```
index.php?route=module/cart&remove=1286:YToxOntpOjYyMzk0O3M6NjoiMTI1MDQxIjt9:
```

Looking at this request i found that in the controller it calls a function from within this statement:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['remove'])) {
        $this->cart->remove($this->request->get['remove']);

        unset($this->session->data['vouchers'][$this->request->get['remove']]);
    }
```

And then from here it calls a remove function in the system/library/cart.php

```
public function remove($key) {
    if (isset($this->session->data['cart'][$key])) {
        unset($this->session->data['cart'][$key]);
    }

    $this->data = array();
}
```

Now.. I know i can easily do a similar get command.. but that key seems to be the product id followed by something else.. Im not sure what this is or how i can access it so i can remove an item from the basket.

If anyone can shed any light on this i'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @shadyyx for his advice on what the serialised information is.

Now, because the item I am wanting to remove from the cart is always the same item and I know what the product id will be, i can simply check what is stored in the session in the cart array. Each item is in this array with its product id and encoded options.

Now loop the cart searching for the product id, and then remove it from the cart with the Ajax code mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look into the `system/library/cart.php` again into the method `add()` - there you can see this code:

```
if (!$option) {
    $key = (int)$product_id;
} else {
    $key = (int)$product_id . ':' . base64_encode(serialize($option));
}
```

I hope now it's clear for you ;-) (if not, ask).

Comment: Ah OK, Thank you for clarifying that. At least now I know where it is coming from.